Prove $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x^2 + 1} = \sqrt{2}$ with $\varepsilon - \delta$
$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x^2 + 1} = \sqrt{2}$
My attempt

Preliminary work:
$$| \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt 2 | = \Bigl| \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt 2)(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt 2)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt 2} \Bigr| = \Bigl|\frac {(x-1)(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt 2} \Bigr|<\Bigl|\frac {(x-1)(x+1)}{x} \Bigr|$$
Further simplifying, using triangle inequality in the first step:
$$\Bigl|\frac {(x-1)(x+1)}{x} \Bigr| < |x-1|\cdot \Bigl(1 + \frac{1}{|x|}\Bigr)=|x-1| + \frac{|x-1|}{|x|}=|x-1|+\Bigr|1-\frac{1}{x}\Bigl|$$
Since we'll be assuming $|x-1|<\delta$ we can make $|x-1|$ small as we want, so we need to find a bound for the other summand. From $|x-1|<\delta$ it follows (omitted how it follows for brevity) $\Bigr|1 - \frac{1}{x}\Bigl|<\frac{\delta}{\delta +1}$
So now we have a bound on both summands: $$|x-1|+\Bigr|1-\frac{1}{x}\Bigl| < \delta + \frac{\delta}{\delta +1} < \delta + \frac{\delta}{\delta} = \delta + 1$$
Finally, choice of $\delta = \varepsilon - 1$ should work.
The formal proof should go here, but I'm omitting it because it's too much to write out and I'd be essentially going backwards in what I've done in the preliminary work. Is the choice of $\delta$ good, is there a more straightforward way to prove this, that I'm missing?

Just to note, if $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then $\delta = \varepsilon - 1 < 0$.

You are making your life unnecessarily complicated. Use the estimate $| \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt 2 | \le {1 \over \sqrt{2}} |x+1||x-1|$ instead (or similar). If $|x-1| < \delta$, then $| \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt 2 | \le {1 \over \sqrt{2}} (2+ \delta) \delta$.

Rather than make the estimate $|x| < \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{2}$, I would instead use $1 + \sqrt{2} < \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{2}$ (or even just $1$, and omit the $\sqrt{2}$). This means you don't have to worry about the expression blowing up around $x = 0$, and might make things easier.

@copper.hat thanks for saying it like that and reminding me that I didn’t lose the habit of complicating stuff.. yes, your suggestion is way simpler, thank you

@powerline We have all been there :-)

Well, building upon the comments above, perhaps something roughly like $|\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} +\sqrt{2}}| \le |(x-1)(x+1)| \le |(x-1)||(x+1)| \le \delta(\delta + 2) = \epsilon \implies \delta = \frac{\sqrt{4 + 4\epsilon}-2}{2}$, or similar.

@JeffreyHarkness nice!

As a training exercise, you can even try to find the "best" (i.e. largest allowed) $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$, and plug together two such epsilon-delta proofs: one for $\sqrt u$ at $u=2$ and one for $1+x^2$ at $x=1$:$$|\sqrt{2+h}-\sqrt2|\le\varepsilon\impliedby|h|\le\delta:=2\sqrt2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2,$$ and$$|(1+(1+k)^2)-2|\le\delta\impliedby|k|\le\sqrt{1+\delta}-1.$$
